# Bash shell for loop process with two paired variable names

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

It's common to use bash shell for example to bulk rename plenty files. Usually I used the following structure,

```
for file in ./*.short
do
# do command
done
```

That's for filename with .short extension. But, now how to process with two or more variable names (in this case file extension) in command? I would like to do bulk process for the following command,

```
( x2x +sf < data.short | frame -l 400 -p 80 | \
bcut +f -l 400 -s 65 -e 65 |\
window -l 400 -L 512 | spec -l 512 |\
glogsp -l 512 -x 8 -p 2 ;\
\
bcut +f -n 20 -s 65 -e 65 < data.mcep |\
mgc2sp -m 20 -a 0.42 -g 0 -l 512 | glogsp -l 512 -x 8 ) | xgr
```

In that case I have .short and .mcep that I want to process concurrently. I use the **and** logic (&&) but it didn't works,

```
for file1 in ./*.short && ./*.mcep
do
# $file1 and file2 process
done
```

Any experienced and skilled shell programmer want to share how to solve this? I have idea to used nested loops, but I don't know how to implemented in Bash.

Comment: So you want to run one command in the files with .short extension and another command for the files with .mcep extension?

Comment: Yes! But is mixed.

Comment: Ok I'll try to write a script and tell if you it works

Comment: Is there a matching `.mcep` file for each `.short` file? if so, you just need to loop over one and create the other by substitution e.g. `"${file%.short}.mcep"`

Comment: @steeldriver, I am thinking the same idea, and it works! because .short and .mcep is pair. However, it just substitute the variable, it didn't cover two or more variables name. Should I mark as solved or change/edit the question?

Comment: @bagustris I have posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.short 
do
(x2x +sf < $file | frame -l 400 -p 80 | 
bcut +f -l 400 -s 65 -e 65 |
window -l 400 -L 512 | spec -l 512 |
glogsp -l 512 -x 8 -p 2 ;\

bcut +f -n 20 -s 65 -e 65 < ${file%.short}.mcep |\
mgc2sp -m 20 -a 0.42 -g 0 -l 512 | glogsp -l 512 -x 8 ) | psgr > ${file%.short}.eps
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the *.shorts and then check for corresponding *.mcep files with:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.short
do
   base=${i%%?????}
   if [ -e ${base}mcep ]
   then
      echo ${base}.short
      echo ${base}.mcep
   fi
done
```

I just echoed the *.short and *.mcep names here but you can now use them in commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script

```
#!/bin/bash

for file1 in /path/to/files/*
do
    ext=${file#*.}

    if [[ "$ext" == "mcep" ]]
    then 
        #command to run on files with 'mcep' extension
    elif [[ "$ext" == "short" ]]
    then
        #command to run on files with 'short' extension
    fi
done
```