# How to run perform different actions from one script

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I run different commands from one script? For example, if I want to run `myscript new filename` to create this file, and run `myscript del filename` to delete this file.

At this moment I have a script that receives the variable and preforms an action upon it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"
      do
        touch $var".txt"
      done
```

Comment: Please take a look this link, it uses two variables, http://askubuntu.com/questions/631996/bash-shell-for-loop-process-with-two-paired-variable-names/632041#632041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == 'new' ]]; then
  touch "$2" && echo "File $2 is created"
elif [[ $1 == 'del' ]]; then
  rm "$2" && echo "File $2 is removed"
else
   echo "THe first srgument can be 'new' or 'del'"
fi
```

- If the first argument to the script `$1` is `new` then the filename given in second argument `$2` will be created and the user will be notified
- Accordingly if `$1` is `del` then the file given in `$2` will be removed and user will be notified
- In other cases user will be given a notification os correct usage patten

**Example :**

```
$ ls -1
scr.sh

$ ./scr.sh new foo
File foo is created

$ ls -1
foo
scr.sh

$ ./scr.sh new bar
File bar is created

$ ls -1
bar
foo
scr.sh

$ ./scr.sh del foo
File foo is removed

$ ls -1
bar
scr.sh

$ ./scr.sh foobar
THe first srgument can be 'new' or 'del'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you know how the arguements work($1, $2, etc.)
You'll need to create an if statement:
    if [ "$1" == "del"]
      then
        rm $var
    fi

Tutorial: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 0):

in shell scripting you can get the arguments by using $n where n is the position of the argument.

So, if you want to run `# myscript new <filename>`, then the *new* action can be obtained by using `$1`.

Then you could build a simple conditional block to perform different actions, like:

`if [ $1 == "new" ]; then
 ....
 ....
 fi`

Let me know if you can't realize how to continue and I'll help you!
Good luck.